# Merging two incomplete datasets in R with the same and different column names

Tags: r, merge, dataset

I think the best way to illustrate this is via example.

```
I have my primary dataset:
ID  ColA    ColB        ColC        ColE
2   Leaf    Dirt                     1
4   Plant   Rock                     2 
1   Tree    Mountain                 3
9   Grass   Boulder                  4
5   Weed    Dust                     5
12                      Sky          A
11                      Cloud        B
6                       Blue         C
7                       Atmosphere   D  
8                       White        E
```

Then the second dataset I want to combine my primary with

```
ID  ColA    ColB            ColD
6   2x2     11x1             11
7   3x3     16x6             12
8   6x6     17x7             13
11  8x8     18x8             14
12  0x0     19x9             15
```

The end result should be

```
   ID   ColA    ColB        ColC        ColE  ColD
    2   Leaf    Dirt         NA          1     NA
    4   Plant   Rock         NA          2     NA
    1   Tree    Mountain     NA          3     NA
    9   Grass   Boulder      NA          4     NA
    5   Weed    Dust         NA          5     NA
    12  0x0     19x9         Sky         A     15
    11  8x8     18x8         Cloud       B     14
    6   2x2     11x1         Blue        C     13
    7   3x3     16x6         Atmosphere  D     12
    8   6x6     17x7         White       E     11
```

I am not concerned with how the ID's are sorted, but I want to keep the order of the column names of the primary dataset the same. All columns in the second dataset that do not have the same column name as the primary goes to the very right of the primary dataset as shown in the example with ColD.

Every time I attempt to write my merge function, I end up getting all kinds of repeats, doubles, or columns that don't actually merge together.

As you can see, these two datasets are both incomplete in certain areas, what is a good way to merge both of these?

Thank you.

EDIT: LukeA your solution gave me this:

```
ID  ColA    ColB       ColC       ColE   ColD
2   Leaf    Dirt                   1    NA
4   Plant   Rock                   2    NA
1   Tree    Mountain               3    NA
9   Grass   Boulder                4    NA
5   Weed    Dust                   5    NA
12                    Sky          A    NA
11                    Cloud        B    NA
6                     Blue         C    NA
7                     Atmosphere   D    NA
8                     White        E    NA
6   2x2     11x1      NA          NA    11
7   3x3     16x6      NA          NA    12
8   6x6     17x7      NA          NA    13
11  8x8     18x8      NA          NA    14
12  0x0     19x9      NA          NA    15
```

Comment: Try `plyr::rbind.fill(df1, df2)`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It didn't work quite as expected, see the edit I made to show the result of that line of code.

Comment: Ah, now I see ... was too quick.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one quick & dirty approach that would work for your example:

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, "ID", all = T)
df3[df3 == ""] <- NA
df3 <- df3[match(df1$ID, df3$ID), ]
df3[!complete.cases(df3[c("ColA.x", "ColB.x")]), c("ColA.x", "ColB.x")] <- df3[!complete.cases(df3[c("ColA.x", "ColB.x")]), c("ColA.y", "ColB.y")]
df3 <- df3[, !names(df3) %in% c("ColA.y", "ColB.y")]
names(df3)[2:3] <- c("ColA", "ColB")
df3
#    ID  ColA     ColB       ColC ColE ColD
# 2   2  Leaf     Dirt       <NA>    1   NA
# 3   4 Plant     Rock       <NA>    2   NA
# 1   1  Tree Mountain       <NA>    3   NA
# 8   9 Grass  Boulder       <NA>    4   NA
# 4   5  Weed     Dust       <NA>    5   NA
# 10 12   0x0     19x9        Sky    A   15
# 9  11   8x8     18x8      Cloud    B   14
# 5   6   2x2     11x1       Blue    C   11
# 6   7   3x3     16x6 Atmosphere    D   12
# 7   8   6x6     17x7      White    E   13
```